# Devise: Nested sign up form when the user and profile are separate models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, nested-forms, rails-models

I'm and usings devise for my authentication and would like to keep the details of my users in a separate model called profile. Profile contains information like first and last name. I want to be able to have a single sign up form that will be able to have all this information entered.

This is my form

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <% fields_for :profile do |fa| %>
            <%= fa.label :first_name %>
            <%= fa.text_field :first_name %>

            <%= fa.label :last_name %>
            <%= fa.text_field :last_name %>
        <% end %>

        <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

        <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

        <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

        <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
    <% end %>
```

This in my user.rb model

```
has_one :profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

When I submit the from it doesn't save the first and last name to the database

Comment: After much searching around, this was the simplest answer to my question. Although I'm not sure this the rails way of doing things

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307743/profile-model-for-devise-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching around, this was the simplest answer to my question. Although I'm not sure this the rails way of doing things

[Profile model for Devise users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307743/profile-model-for-devise-users)