# Rails : Set form inputs with a has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-one

In my rails app, I have a relation between User table (which is dedicated to authentication purpose) and Store table (which contains store information, like the name, description,...).

I mapped the two models like this:

- User has_one :store
- Store belongs_to :user

In the registration phase, I need to ask for both authentication information (I'm using Devise gem) like email and password, and the store name. This mean that I would like to fill two connected tables (User and Store) using the same form!

**How does the ERB (or Haml) form looks like, especially for the Store Name part?**

I tried this, but it doesn't work (more specifically, the line asking for store name):

```
= form_for(resources, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
    = f.text_field :store[:name]
    = f.email_field :email
    = f.password_field :password
    = f.submit "Create"
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for):

```
= f.fields_for :store do |store_field|
  = store_field.text_field :name
```

And in your User model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :store
```

Comment: Thanks for yor help Oscar, it works half! When I add `fields_for` the input is created. But when I add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :store` the input disappear!! I tried without the accepts_nested_attributes but I get MassAssignment error :/

Comment: You may have to replace :store with @user.store

Comment: The problem is that `@user` doesn't exist, because it's the registration page: `@user` and `@store` don't exist yet!

Comment: What is resources? You need to have the relationship in the object in order to use fields_for.

Comment: I finally get it. This problem was solved in the following page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307743/profile-model-for-devise-users. Here, `resources` is generated by Devise gem to authenticate a user.