# Devise: Associated Model on Sign Up: Can't mass-assign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, user-management

I setup Devise on `User` model with its default options.

I also have a `Company` model that needs to add data added whenever a user registers. A company owner setups a `User` to login with and a `Company` profile, both in the same form.

I setup `Company` model with `has_many :users` and `User` with `has_one :company`, but I keep getting `Can't mass-assign protected` when submitting the form. I followed [Profile model for Devise users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307743/profile-model-for-devise-users) and others from Stackoverflow, but no luck.

How can I setup the `User` and `Company` model to add the necessary data whenever a user registers? User data to `User` and company data to `Company`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I got it working:

My `User` model has:

```
attr_accessible :company_attributes

belongs_to :company
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
```

My `Company` model has:

```
has_many :users
```

And the `new.html.erb` from `devise/registrations` is with the following added:

```
<% resource.build_company %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
[ fields for User ]
<%= f.fields_for :company_attributes, resource.company do |company| %>
[ fields for Company ]
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback to create a object Company after create a user, for example on your `User.rb` model add: (I don't know your company attributes but you can take a look to this example)

```
after_create :first_company
 def first_company
  company = self.company.new(:title => "Company title here", :created_at => Time.now #add more attributes if required)
  board.save!
 end
```

You must add `attr_accessible` to attributes that you receive from your action controller.
Add the next code on your models to remove the `Can't mass-assign protected`

`attr_accessible :title #...more attributes if required`

Regards!

Comment: i like this solution because it doesn't involve the view, nor does it require overriding the devise controller. however, i haven't seen this answer around to solve this sort of problem. is there a down side to doing it this way?

Comment: also, what does `board.save!` do? is that supposed to be `company.save!`?