# How to create form_tag for sign up form which will save form data in two different tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

As it is basic question but I am confused as I have to create one sign up form which will have to save data in two different tables like
1) salon 2) users
I have salons data like business name adress url these all fields should save in salon table
and email and password and adress should save in users table.
how to do this in good way

my view source code is something like this

```
<%= form_tag users_path(@users), :method => :post do |f| %>


<%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%=  label_tag :business_name %><br />
  <%= text_field_tag :business_name %></div

  <div><%=  label_tag :website_url %><br />
  https://<%= text_field_tag :website %></div>

  <div><%=  label_tag :business_adress %><br />
  <%= text_field_tag :business_adress %></div>


  <div><%=  label_tag :owners_name %><br />
  <%= text_field_tag :name %></div>

  <div><%=  label_tag :phone_number %><br />
  <%= text_field_tag :phone_number %></div>

  <div><%=  label_tag :email %><br />
  <%= email_field_tag :email %></div>

  <div><%= label_tag :password %><br />
  <%= password_field_tag :password %></div>

  <div><%= label_tag :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= password_field_tag :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= submit_tag "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Also I want to know how controller side code would be managed and saved the fields data in different table

Comment: What is the relation between `user` and `salon` ?

Answer (score 1):

In controller Users_controller will be look like this:-
`rails 4 with strong parameters`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def create
   @user = User.create!(user_params)
   @user.salons.create!(salon_params)
 end

private
 def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit!(:name,:phone,:email, :password) #permit those parameters which you required 
 end
 def salon_params
   params.permit!(:business_name, :website, :business_adress) 
 end 
end
```

In Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base           
     has_many :salons        
  end
```

Thanks Hope it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create association between the two models, check this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to know about rails associations.

Once you created association between the models, checkout this [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to know about nested attributes, which allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent.

Example,

> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> ```
>   has_many :salons, :dependent =>:destroy   
>
>   accepts_nested_attributes_for :salons
> ```
>
> end
>
> class Salon < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> belongs_to :user
>
> end

then in your UserController's new action you need to build salon like this,

> @user = User.new
>
> @user.salons.build

then in your user form you can get value for salon from user like this

> ```
> <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
>   ...
>
>   <%= f.fields_for :salons do |builder| %>
>     <%= f.text_field :business_name %>
>     ...
>   <% end %>
>   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
> <% end %>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using devise as authentication solution, and you already have the relationship between them set up, you might want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307743/profile-model-for-devise-users) to which the accepted answer essentially is:

1. run `rails generate devise:views` inside your rails app's directory to extract the devise signup form and insert your form with the modifications below into it.
2. modify the extracted form (app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb) to create an empty salon beforehand (`resource.build_salon`)
3. instead of placing your salon model's form fields inside the main surrounding `form_for` block create a nested block using `fields_for :salon do |s|`
4. and place all form fields which belong to your salon model into that block so it ends up looking like this

   ```
   <%= form_tag users_path(@users), :method => :post do |f| %>

   <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <%= f.fields_for :salon do |s| %>
      <div><%= s.label :business_name %><br />
      <%= s.text_field :business_name %></div

      <div><%= s.label :website_url %><br />
      https://<%= s.text_field :website %></div>

    <% end %>

    <div><%=  label_tag :email %><br />
    <%= email_field_tag :email %></div>

    <div><%= label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= password_field_tag :password %></div>

    <div><%= label_tag :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= password_field_tag :password_confirmation %></div>

    <div><%= submit_tag "Sign up" %></div>
   <% end %>
   ```

Hope this helps