# Creating Profile for Devise users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

So I took the steps described in [Profile model for Devise users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307743/profile-model-for-devise-users)
I'm using rails 4 and ruby 1.9.3p448

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 

attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :profile_attributes
has_one :profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile       


protected

def profile
  super || build_profile
end 

end
```

#

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :uname, :manager
end
```

#

```
<h2>Sign up...</h2>
<%= form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>

<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>
<div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>  

<%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>
  <h2><%= profile_form.label :uname %></h2>
  <p><%= profile_form.text_field :uname %></p>  
  <h2><%= profile_form.label :manager %></h2>
  <p><%= profile_form.text_field :manager %></p>
<% end %>  

<div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

#

Still can't save profile for user and this is the output:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kG7S9lF4+5hm+ggmKA4LZyXrN4hsPf01jGQvKxgzGGI=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test1@test.test", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "profile_attributes"=>{"uname"=>"1", "manager"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Sign up"} **Unpermitted parameters: profile_attributes**
```

Shoud I do anything in Profiles controller?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution!
In my users/registrations_controller.rb, I had to add the following

```
 before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| 
     u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, 
     profile_attributes: [:uname, :manager])}
end
```

and it works just fine!

Answer (score 3):

Rails 4 has stopped using attr_accessible and has started using strong parameters -http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

You'll need to add your nested attributes for profile into the permitted attributes in the user controller.