# How to create a profile for devise user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm new to rails and trying to create a profile for devise users when they signup, using nested form in devise signup. I've gone through 
[Creating Profile for Devise users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799382/creating-profile-for-devise-users), 
[Profile model for Devise users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307743/profile-model-for-devise-users)
and few other articles to achieve the same but after a day in vain, I'm still trying to make it work. Here is my code.

**Model - user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Model - user_profile.rb**

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Controller - controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| 
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, 
      user_profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name])}
    end
  end
end
```

**View - views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
 <h2>Sign up</h2>
 <% resource.build_user_profile %>
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   <%= devise_error_messages! %>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :email %><br />
     <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :password %>
     <% if @minimum_password_length %>
       <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
     <% end %><br />
     <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
     <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
   </div>

   <%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>
     <%= profile_form.label :first_name %><br/>
     <%= profile_form.text_field :first_name %><br/>

     <%= profile_form.label :last_name %><br/>
     <p><%= profile_form.text_field :last_name %><br/>
   <% end %>

   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
   </div>
 <% end %>

 <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

**Server Log**

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"rLuFXwISxiJpWPjpmKzjnjhKr41F5
56sWbtT+8gslAMsFDWRbl7MSitSXUESjLdZccCBGBGvVv+JbhW7G5py5g==", "user"=>{"email"=>
"zebandz@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTER
ED]", "user_profile_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"Zeban", "last_name"=>"Dezend"}}
, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameter: user_profile_attributes
```

I think, I'm missing the code to fetch the values from params and create a new record. Can someone suggest me the fix ?

Comment: The registration controller is only accepting `user` parameters. 
You will have to inherit and override this controller with your own method that incorporates and permits `user_profile_attributes` also.

[Registration Controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)

Answer (score 1):

please follow the below steps.

devise> reg > new

```
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">

          <h2>Sign up</h2>

          <% resource.build_user_profile if resource.user_profile.nil? %>
          <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url:     registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= devise_error_messages! %>

           <div class="row">
           <%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>
           <div  class="col-md-6">
           <div class="form-group">
             <%= profile_form.label :first_name %>
             <%= profile_form.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control" %>
           </div>
           </div>
           <div  class="col-md-6">
           <div class="form-group">
             <%= profile_form.label :last_name %>
             <%= profile_form.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          </div>
          <% end %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email %><br />
          <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

          <%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>
          <div class="form-group">
           <%= profile_form.label :business_name %>
           <%= profile_form.text_field :business_name, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <%= profile_form.label :business_category %>
           <%= profile_form.collection_select :business_category_id, BusinessCategory.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select Category"}, {class: "form-control"} %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= profile_form.label :website %>
            <%= profile_form.url_field :website, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <%= profile_form.label :address %>
           <%= profile_form.text_area :address, class: "form-control" %>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <%= profile_form.label :personal_number %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :phone_number, class: "form-control" %>
         </div>


    <div class="form-group">
         <%= profile_form.label :office_number %>
         <%= profile_form.text_field :office_number, class: "form-control" %>

   </div>
<% end %> 

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
  <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
  <% end %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
</div>



user reg controller

def new
    # Override Devise default behaviour and create a profile as well
    build_resource({})
    resource.build_user_profile
    respond_with self.resource
  end

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u|
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_profile_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name, :business_name, :business_category_id, :website, :address, :phone_number, :office_number])
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following these steps from their github page?
They set the permitted parameters in the ApplicationController. Also the structure is a little different. The parameters go into `keys`.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
end
```