# Creating employee with devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

It looks like this 
[Profile model for Devise users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307743/profile-model-for-devise-users)
but mine is different.

I want to create employee record and this employee have an option to have a user account or not. I am using devise gem for my user.

So I have Employee model with

```
has_one :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

and User model

```
belongs_to :employee
```

I know that I need to put nested user in my view, But how to save it in controller?

It is not something like this, right?

```
params.require(:employee).permit(:name, user_attributes: [:email, :password])
```

Can you give some hint or some useful link I can follow? It is hard to modify the devise. Thank you ^_^

Comment: so why is this not working? how does the params hash look? how is your form ?

Comment: It is working but the password is not encrypted. And I think this is a bad code to do like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Devise**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) shouldn't be modified; it's just a series of controllers and a model.

If you want to create an `employee`, and then pass data through to the `User` model, you've taken the right approach.

What you'll need to do is keep to convention (IE build the `User` model etc) to ensure the functionality of Devise is maintained:

---

```
#app/controllers/employees_controller.rb
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @employee = Employee.new
      @employee.build_user
   end

   def create
      @employee = Employee.new employee_params
      @employee.save
   end

   private

   def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(:name, user_attributes: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
   end
end
```

Now, the only problem with this is that `user_attributes` may be false, as Devise is famously finicky with its strong params.

--

To get the form to work, you'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/views/employees/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @employee do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.fields_for :user do |user| %>
      <%= user.email_field :email %>
      <%= user.password_field :password %>
      <%= user.password_field :password_confirmation %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I don't have any reason - or tests - to disprove this. [Devise even suggests](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app) that you can load forms using the `User.new` invocation. Thus, I'd surmise that the main hurdle you'll have is the passing of the strong params.

Comment: Thank you for this. How about on edit? can I use `employee_params` also? where I will declare `current_password` field? Because I tried to save it, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I didn't misunderstood, but no need to modify Devise. 
Just pass all params you need and if valid, create the user directly:

```
params.require(:employee).permit(:name, 
                                 :user_wants_account, 
                                 :whatever, 
                                 :user => [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])

# manually
User.create(:email => params[:employee][:user][:email], 
            :password => params[:employee][:user][:password], 
            :password_confirmation => params[:employee][:user][:password_confirmation],
            :employee_id => self)
```

If you want to use the "default" login forms - no problem - since each user has an employee relation...

Comment: how about using `build_resource(params[employee][:user][:email], params[employee][:user][:password])` but how I will use this if my controller is like this `class EmployeesController < ApplicationController`